# How do I fix a function that returns NAN?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-regression, nan, gradient-descent

I wanted to try to implement gradient descent by myself and I wrote this:

```
# Creating random sample dataset
import random as rnd 
dataset = []
for i in range(0, 500):
    d_dataset = [i, rnd.randint((i-4), (i+4))]
    dataset.append(d_dataset)

def gradient_descent(t0, t1, lrate, ds):
    length = len(ds)
    c0, c1 = 0, 0
    for element in ds:
        elx = element[0]
        ely = element[1]
        c0 += ((t0 + (t1*elx) - ely)) 
        c1 += ((t0 + (t1*elx) - ely)*elx) 
    t0 -= (lrate * c0 / length)
    t1 -= (lrate * c1 / length)
    return t0, t1

def train(t0, t1, lrate, trainlimit, trainingset):
    k = 0
    while k < trainlimit:
        new_t0, new_t1 = gradient_descent(t0, t1, lrate, trainingset)
        t0, t1 = new_t0, new_t1
        k += 1
    return t0, t1

print(gradient_descent(20, 1, 1, dataset))
print(train(0, 0, 1, 10000, dataset))
```

Whenever I run this, I get a somewhat normal output from the `gradient_descent()` but I get `(nan, nan)` from the `train()` function. I tried running `train` with the input `(0, 0, 1, 10, dataset)` and I get this value `(-4.705770241957691e+46, -1.5670167612541557e+49)`, which seems very wrong.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this error. Sorry if this has been asked before but I couldn't find any answers on how to fix nan error.

Comment: Is there a chance that ```length = 0``` during some iteration? Because that would cause division by zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `print(train(0, 0, 1, 10000, dataset))`, the values returned by `gradient_descent(t0, t1, lrate, trainingset)` are increasing in every iteration of the `while`-loop. When they become larger than the maximum value allowed for `float`, they will automatically be converted to `float('inf')`, a `float` representing infinity. Check this maximum value on your system with `sys.float_info.max`:

```
import sys
print(sys.float_info.max)
```

However, your function `gradient_descent()` can't handle infinite values, which you can verify with the following call to your function:

```
gradient_descent(float('inf'), float('inf'), 1, dataset)
```

The problem here are the following two lines in `gradient_descent()`, which are not well defined for `t0` and `t1` being infinite:

```
c0 += ((t0 + (t1*elx) - ely)) 
c1 += ((t0 + (t1*elx) - ely)*elx)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I made a major mistake in the algo, thats why this happens. Thanks for your time!

Comment: If my answer helped solve your problem and answered your question, would you please mark it as the correct answer?